# Source attachment to Hadoop 1.2.1

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, hadoop

I'm trying to attach the source from Hadoop 1.2.1 (downloaded from [here](https://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/stable1/)). The problem is that the packages mapred (org.apache.hadoop.mapred) is separate from the core package in the source.

Currently I'm switching between sources during debug time, which is very impractical. What can I do?

Thanks, Pedro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've written a blog post on this subject - you should be able to follow these instructions to build your own source jar from the source:

- http://whiteycode.blogspot.com/2012/05/building-hadoop-source-jars.html